# Displaying profile picture in modal dialog in AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Am working on a modal dialog where in i need to display the profile picture of the user along with other data, the ui should like the image below

[image: Intended UI design]

However the layout design that i have come up is not spanning the image in multiple rows. Below is the current design of my dialog

[image: Current UI Design]

As you can see in the above picture, there is a blank space between Field 2 and Field 3 because of the image that is part of the Field 2. If the height of the image is more then the gap between these fields increases further.

But this is not the intended design. I need to make sure there is no gap or empty space between field 2 and 3 because of the image.

Below is my html

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Field 1: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field1" id="field1" ng-model="field1" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subfield1" id="subfield1" ng-model="subfield1" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Field 2: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field2" id="field2" ng-model="field2" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img class="col-sm-2" src="image.png" class="img-responsive img-circle">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Field 3: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field3" id="field3" ng-model="field3" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Field 4: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field4" id="field4" ng-model="field4" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am using angularjs with bootstrap.

Any pointers to resolve this layout issue will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change your layout. It must contains two cols wrapper, first col contains your main fields, second col contains subfield and image

Also, you can place image as absolute, but it is not the best way

Comment: thanks for the reply. could you please point me to some useful links on this, as am unaware of layouting using cols wrapper

Comment: i figured how to use the columns for layouting. it worked perfect. thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit like text wrapping around images. Add `float:right` style to your image.

```
<div class="col-sm-2" style="float: right">
  <img class="col-sm-2" src="image.png" class="img-responsive img-circle">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. no adding the style effect didn't work

Comment: create a plnkr demo for better troubleshooting?